# Django TypeError when trying to use custom base ModelForm or custom error_class

Tags: django-models, python-2.7, django-forms

I wanted to have  for error_class rendering in forms. I saw this definition and put it into a file in my app directory:

```
from django.forms.util import ErrorList
class DivErrorList(ErrorList):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.as_divs()
    def as_divs(self):
        if not self: return u''
        return u'<div class="errorlist">%s</div>' % \
               ''.join([u'<div class="error">%s</div>' % e for e in self])
```

But, when I try to use it in my view:

```
from sporty import DivErrorList
...
form = LocationForm(request.POST or None, error_class=DivErrorList)
if form.is_valid():
```

I get this error, when submitting the form with an error:
    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py in _clean_fields, line 293.

This is at the form.is_valid() line. If I don't use the error_class, it works fine (only without the desired .

Next, I tried to instead, create a base ModelForm class that uses the DivErrorList in my app directory:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from sporty import DivErrorList

class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs_new = {'error_class': DivErrorList}
        kwargs_new.update(kwargs)
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs_new)
```

and then I defined my ModelForm based on that class and no longer used the error_class argument on the form creation:

```
from sporty import MyModelForm
from sporty.models import Location

class LocationForm(MyModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
```

Now, when I try to even view the form (not submitting it with any data), I get this error:
    TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases module.**init**() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
    /home/pcm/workspace/sportscaster/sporty/forms.py in , line 5

I'm at a loss on both of these. Any ideas? I'd prefer the latter, as all my forms will want to use  for error reporting (I'd like to actually render the form as divs too, as some point.

Comment: BTW, the model just has two fields, a char field that is NOT NULL, and a url field that is null.

Answer (score 0):

Googling around, I found a discussion on type errors and metaclass bases. The issue was that I had a class, MyModelForm, in a file MyModelForm.py, and was then importing the module attempting to use it like a class:

```
from sporty import MyModelForm
```

The solution was to place MyModelForm class into a file modelforms.py and do:

```
from sporty.modelforms import MyModelForm
```

I did the same with DivErrorList, placing the class in the modelforms.py file.